# How to create an Android AVD without HAXM?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, haxm, amd-processor

I'm trying to setup an Android development environment on my computer, and I'm having trouble setting up an AVD, so I can test my applications without having to have a physical device all the time.  However, I'm running into a problem.  The first problem is that when I create an AVD in AVD Manager, it doesn't show up on the AVD list when I try to run my application (yes, I checked the Android target version).  I realized that seems to be because the AVD wants to use HAXM, but my computer seemingly does not support HAXM because it uses an AMD processor and not an Intel processor.

According to Android Studio, one option is to use an ARM system image which does not require HAXM.  However, when I tried to create an ARM image, I still get the same "Your computer does not support HAXM" error in the "recommendations" box on the bottom right, and when I create the AVD it still doesn't show up in my AVD list.

Buying a new computer to do Android development on is not an option to me, I would like to be able to do development on the computer I have.  Also, Intel emulation is not supported in my BIOS.

I also tried running my emulator from the AVD manager directly rather than trying to go through the application Run menu, and I got this error (which appears to have nothing to do with HAXM, but I'm not sure):

```
/home/ertai87/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5X_API_23
/home/ertai87/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator: 1: /home/ertai87/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Screenshots:

[Of the AVD Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On46g.jpg)

[Of the run menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW4sJ.jpg)

[Of the "Create new AVD" select image screen, when selecting ARM images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1AAJ.jpg)

Comment: "The first problem is that when I create an AVD in AVD Manager, it doesn't show up on the AVD list when I try to run my application" -- does it show up in the AVD Manager itself? With regards to the constant HAXM error message, AFAIAC, [that's a bug in Android Studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208345). You might consider uploading some screenshots of what you are seeing somewhere, then linking to those screenshots in your question.

Comment: Yes, it shows up in AVD manager.  When I try to run it through AVD Manager I get the error message I posted at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: What does line 1 of `/home/ertai87/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator` look like?

Comment: /home/ertai87/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator is a compiled executable.

As for the screenshots, my previous reply was posted from my phone, but I'm on my computer now so I will edit my OP with them.  Sorry for the wait.

Comment: Sorry, with that error message, I thought that it was a shell script.

Comment: Makes sense, I did as well, until I actually checked it as per your suggestion.  Anyway, I also added screenshots.  The screenshots were taken in the order that I listed them in the OP, without changing any settings in-between (so the Android Studio configuration is the exact same between all of them)

Comment: Do you get any useful messages if you try clicking the Run button (green arrow) for your AVD in the AVD Manager? Is an update available for the "Android SDK Tools" item in the SDK Manager?

Comment: Nope.  What happens when I click the "Run" button is the "Of the run menu" screenshot window pops up and that's it.

Comment: I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling Android Studio and the SDK packages just in case that did something, because I had a disk space error when I installed it the first time which might have corrupted something (I since cleaned out my disk so I have sufficient space now).  That didn't fix anything.

Comment: When I reinstalled Android Studio I paid more attention to the messages that popped up.  Apparently my computer is hardware acceleration enabled, but I need some kind of KVM virtualization something or other (didn't note the exact name).  Googling "android acceleration kvm" got me this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/564910/kvm-is-not-installed-on-this-machine-dev-kvm-is-missing .  I ran kvm-ok and it told me that my computer can use kvm acceleration, but how do I enable it?  Maybe that will help...

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation (or the equivalent for your distro, if it is not Ubuntu). KVM is definitely required on Linux.

Comment: Alright, so I followed those instructions (I am using Ubuntu, 14.04 to be precise), then I logged off and logged back on, and nothing changed.

By the way, my BIOS doesn't have an option to enable virtualization, so I just presume it's always on, since kvm-ok says it's working. Also, I didn't know this before, but apparently I'm running a 32-bit OS on a 64-bit processor.  Until just now, I thought my processor was 32-bit so I installed a 32-bit OS on it.  While I'd prefer not to use the nuclear option, reinstalling a 64-bit OS is an option if required.