# Unable to deploy to Genymotion device through Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, genymotion

I'm currently using Genymotion with Android Studio via the Genymotion plugin to try to test and debug my Android applications.  I set up the Android Studio Genymotion plugin a while ago, and it worked.  However, just now I tried to deploy my application to Genymotion, but after starting my Genymotion device, it did not appear in the ADB deployment list.  I have no idea what happened or why.  Does anyone have any idea?

By the way, this means I cannot test my application, as I cannot use the regular ADB virtual device set as per this other continuing issue: [How to create an Android AVD without HAXM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196960/how-to-create-an-android-avd-without-haxm)

Thanks!

Comment: What is your current version of Genymotion?

Comment: Version 2.6.0
Revision 20151127-3674435
License Type: Personal Use

Answer (score 0):

It is potentially an incompatibility problem between the adb shipped with Genymotion and the one from your Android SDK.

Turn all your Genymotion devices off.

Then open Genymotion application (not the IDE plugin),  go to settings > adb tab > check "use custom adb" and set the path to yout Android SDK.

Then reopen a device and you should see it on your IDE.

Comment: It's already set to that.  Should I reset it?  If so how would I even do that?  Also, who is "we"?  Are you a Google employee?  If so, could we communicate a bit closer?  I'm having some other issues as well.

Comment: Here are some screenshots for you.  They were all taken sequentially; the only thing I did between taking each screenshot was opening the appropriate menu to get the proper window view.

http://imgur.com/a/XTslb

As for any error messages I'm receiving, there are no new ones beyond the ones that were detailed in this other question I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196960/how-to-create-an-android-avd-without-haxm

Comment: Sorry, I a Genymotion team member. I fixed the post to make the sentence clear. This is apparently not the solution for your problem. What you should do is to type "adb devices" on a terminal to check if the device is seen by adb or not. Make sure also that you use the last version of Genymotion, we had a bug recently that produced the disappearance of the devices on Android Studio.